# How to stop Windows 7 from reducing screen brightness when operating on battery?

Tags: windows-7, power-management

Every time I turn the laptop on while not plugged in and working on battery, the screen brightness gets reduced automatically down to about 50-60%. When I plug it in, it remains at that level so I have to go to the Control Panel and readjust it.

Is there any way to have Windows keep screen brightness where I set it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to change plan settings, then set a constant equal brightness level for each plan.

If required, go into advanced settings from the plan settings page, and change the settings under Display for every plan present to match your needs.